# Can I require that a protocol's associated type is a protocol itself in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, swift-protocols, associated-types

## Question

I have a protocol defined as follows:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MySubprotocol
}
```

Can I require that the associated type `MySubprotocol` is a protocol as well?

So semantically it would be sth. like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MySubprotocol: AnyProtocol
}
```

## Background

I know that I can do nothing with that protocol inside a given concrete type that implements `MyProtocol`, but I can use it "from outside" for protocol composition. My ultimate goal would be to define a "Sum protocol" from all the associated types of all `MyProtocol` implementations, e.g. when I have the following structs that implement `MyProtocol`,

```
struct MyImpl_1: MyProtocol {
    typealias MySubProtocol = MySubProtocol_1
}

struct MyImpl_2: MyProtocol {
    typealias MySubProtocol = MySubProtocol_2
}

...
```

I want to create a composite protocol like this:

```
protocol AllRequirements: 
    MyImpl_1.MySubprotocol,
    MyImpl_2.MySubprotocol, 
    ... {}
```

This requires `MyImpl_1.MySubprotocol` etc. to be a protocol, otherwise I can't compose it. (I know, I could use the concrete type `MySubProtocol_1` instead, but I want compile-time safety when a developer creates a new implementation of `MyProtocol` (i.e. another `MyImpl_n`).

## Example Use Case

I have a couple of "Worker" objects, each of which performs a specific task. As I want to enforce a common API, I create a common protocol for all of these types:

```
protocol: Worker {
    associatedtype Toolset
    func getTheJobDone()
}
```

Here's an example for a concrete type:

```
struct Cleaner: Worker {
    typealias Toolset = AnyBrush

    let brush: AnyBrush

    init(brush: AnyBrush) {
       self.brush = brush
    }

    func getTheJobDone() {
        brush.applyToFloor()
    }
}
```

In practice, I will have multiple types of this sort to perform different tasks. I want each of these Workers to define their own requirements, i.e. the interface (protocol) they require to get their job done. So in this case, I would create a protocol `AnyBrush` along with the `Cleaner`:

```
protocol AnyBrush {
    func applyToFloor()
}
```

which I then require as the worker's `Toolset` (see above).

This approach works for me, but when I create a new `Worker` type, the current protocol definition will allow me to specify any type for the `Toolset`, so someone could (for some unknown reason) do this:

```
typealias Toolset = Int
```

which doesn't make sense at all.

So that's why I'm asking this question. For these two goals:

1. Force a common interface (API) for all workers.
2. Use the compiler to enforce that the associated type `Toolset` is always a protocol.

One might ask me to trust my co-workers and my future self that we're going to use a protocol because if we don't understand that, we got a much more serious problem, but I would still like to see if it's possible to require a protocol.

Comment: Probably an xy problem. Please describe (or better, show) the actual use case. What's the _real_ goal?

Comment: The real goal is rather complex, it's about the pattern. Added an example to make the pattern clearer and why it would be nice to have this protocol requirement for it.

Comment: Uhm yeah, thanks I guess. I appreciate it when people point me towards errors in my thinking. It might very well be the case here. But I find it neither respectful nor helpful to say that anyone's question is nonsense.

Comment: You can limit the associated type to types that _adopt_ a certain protocol by using a constraint in the usual way. But you cannot say that the associated type must _be_ a protocol; a protocol is not a type.

Comment: That answers the question, thank you. It's rather strange though that you can set a `typealias` for a protocol. If a protocol is not a type, then there can't be a `typealias` for it. Same with the `associatedtype`.

Comment: It's not that strange; it's an equivocation on the meaning of the word "type".